# Passing encrypted email in url string for Commerce Cloud - Key Management

Tags: marketing-cloud, encryption, commerce-cloud, key

I need to utilize the encryptsymmetric ampscript function to pass an email through to Commerce Cloud that is encrypted.

The guys on commerce cloud have generated a private and public key.  I cannot import the cert. file associated to the public key so, I just copied the txt string and attempted to encrypt the email value but it doesn't appear to be working.

We're also utilizing a SALT and an initial vector with this encrption string.

`https://www.sample.com?e=%%=EncryptSymmetric(emailaddr, "AES;mode=ecb;padding=none", 'CC_Public2', @null, 'Sample Salt2', @null, 'initVector', @null)=%%`

I can't find this specific process documented anywhere especially when it comes to what type of cert files can be uploaded to asymmetric keys or whether or not a plain text key can be copied into the symmetric key field without being truncated.

Comment: Where have you done that: "Created a sample key, public key, SALT and an initial vector"?

Comment: Witching marketing cloud > admin > key management

Comment: Within* not witching...

Comment: Have you done this after https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/WebServices/Importcertificatesforaninstance.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symmetric encryption: only one key is involved. The parties share that key - one party encrypts with the key, the other party decrypts with the same key. Asymmetric encryption - two keys (public and private) are involved. One party encrypts with public key, the other party decrypts with the private key.

[EncryptSymmetric](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/EncryptSymmetric.htm) is a symmetric encryption function as its name suggests and it cannot use private/public keys generated for asymmetric crypto case.

Commerce Cloud supports both symmetric and asymmetric encryption algorithms, Marketing Cloud (at least in AMPScript) only supports symmetric. You want to do this:

1. Pick a symmetric cipher. This includes the name of the algorithm and optional mode and padding values (for DES/3DES only)
2. Generate a symmetric key
3. Optionally, generate salt and initialization strings. The need to do so depends on the cipher chosen.

Communicate all three items to the other party. The examples in [EncryptSymmetric](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/EncryptSymmetric.htm) show steps #1 and #3.

To verify encryption / decryption with your keys outside of Salesforce, I recommend [cryptii.com](https://cryptii.com) . Here's a screenshot of your encryption / decryption pipeline with AES-256 as the cipher and a randomly generated key + initialization vector

[image: encryption / decryption pipeline with AES-256 as the cipher]

Comment: Is this not supported across clouds as stated in this documentation?  "Marketing Cloud does not support the use of these functions in conjunction with outside or third-party encryption and decryption functionality."  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DecryptSymmetric.htm?search_text=key%20management

Comment: The terms "outside" (of SFMC), "third-party" and "supported" might mean something to e.g. SF product support...but technically speaking, there's no issue per se.  You can encrypt/decrypt and send/receive to/from outside. Standard encryption algorithms being used imply that both sides (incl. an outside party) can encrypt/decrypt as long as you adhere to the agreed-upon crypto scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Only the following file types are allowed for import on Salesforce Commerce Cloud B2C Commerce instance:

- Trusted certificates: .crt .pem .cer .der
- Private Keys: .p12 .pfx

Try providing the private key in .p12 or .pfx format to Commerce Cloud.

See https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/WebServices/Importcertificatesforaninstance.html

Comment: Where this is helpful from an import into Commerce Cloud, it doesn't answer the question since I'm looking to do the opposite.  Public Key on SFMC, Private Key on CC.