# Encrypt Symmetric and Decrypt Off-Platform

Tags: marketing-cloud, encryption, decrypt

I have been asked to encrypt a URL parameter for a project that sends the customer to a non-marketing cloud corporate site. Encryption is easy enough:

```
  set @encryptedString = EncryptSymmetric(@string, "AES", @null, @password, @null, @salt, @null, @vector)
  set @encodedEncryptedString = Base64Encode(@encryptedSring)
```

However, the website developers are having some trouble decrypting the encoded and encrypted string. Given the password, salt, and vector, how can we decrypt this string? Can someone point me to some documentation that would describe the process?

Comment: As far as I know its not possible, from this link:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/EncryptSymmetric.htm

Marketing Cloud does not support the use of these functions in conjunction with outside or third-party encryption and decryption functionality.

Comment: What values are you trying to send in @String? Is it private/sensitive customer data that MUST be encrypted, or can it be sent as "obfuscated" text?

Comment: I've done it. Details here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/157898/5202

Comment: Take a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/255235/passing-encrypted-email-in-url-string-for-commerce-cloud-key-management , it walks through a similar scenario.

Comment: Regarding Marketing Cloud not supporting it and the doc saying so, reproducing my comment from the other thread: _the terms "outside" (of SFMC), "third-party" and "supported" might mean something to e.g. SF product support...but technically speaking, there's no issue per se. You can encrypt/decrypt and send/receive to/from outside. Standard encryption algorithms being used imply that both sides (incl. an outside party) can encrypt/decrypt as long as you adhere to the agreed-upon crypto scheme_